# accumulation points in $\mathbb R$

Tags: general-topology, product-space

Consider the subset $A = [a, b)$ of $\mathbb R$. Then it is easily verified that every element in $[a, b)$ is a limit point of $A$. The point $b$ is also a limit point of $A$. Why?

Comment: Because there are points in $A$ that are arbitrarily close to $b$.

Comment: Wikipedia for limit point: In mathematics, a limit point (or cluster point or accumulation point) of a set S in a topological space X is a point x that can be "approximated" by points of S in the sense that every neighbourhood of x with respect to the topology on X *also contains a point of S other than x itself*. A limit point of a set S *does not itself have to be an element of S*. Emphasis added.

Comment: Any nhd of $b $ contains a point from $A $.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because every open interval centered at $b$ contained infinitely many points of $[a,b).$

In other words b is the limit of the sequence $$\{b-1/n\}_{n=k}^{\infty}$$ for some $k>0.$